# Pandas groupby: treat two columns as one

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe, two of the columns are latitude and longitude. Each lat-lon pair represents a single location, and I would like to groupby that location.

I could do this groupby operation by converting the two columns into a single column of tuples, and groupby that column. However, my actual dataframe is extremely large, and adding another column could really slow things down. I would like to know if there is a more idiomatic way to do this in pandas.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd                                                                                                                                                                                 
In [2]: import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                                  
In [3]: key  = np.random.randint(low = 1, high = 20, size = 100) 
   ...: data = np.random.random(size = (100)) 
   ...: d1   = {'key':key, 'time':range(1,101), 'data':data} 
   ...: df1  = pd.DataFrame(d1) 
   ...: print(df1.shape) 
   ...: df1.head()                                                                                                                                                                                                 
(100, 3)
Out[3]: 
    key  time      data
0     3     1  0.778231
1    13     2  0.822494
2     4     3  0.053416
3     8     4  0.894341
4     7     5  0.884310
In [4]: key = range(1,21) 
   ...: lat = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = 90, size = 20) 
   ...: lon = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = 90, size = 20) 
   ...: d2  = {'key':key, 'lat':lat, 'lon':lon} 
   ...: df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2) 
   ...: print(df2.shape) 
   ...: df2.head()                                                                                                                                                                                                 
(20, 3)
Out[4]: 
    key  lat  lon
0     1   36   81
1     2    6   57
2     3   84    4
3     4   61    0
4     5   54   69
In [5]: result = pd.merge(df1, df2).sort_values('time') 
   ...: result.head()                                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[5]: 
    key  time      data  lat  lon
0     3     1  0.778231   84    4
4    13     2  0.822494   12   19
13    4     3  0.053416   61    0
18    8     4  0.894341   49   34
23    7     5  0.884310    8   13
```

(Make sure to scroll down in the box to see the output of `In [5]` as that is what my final dataframe looks like)

At this point I would like to be able to do something like `result.groupby(('lat','lon'))` and have pandas treat both columns as one. Is there a way to do this? Or should I just bite the bullet and make a new column of tuples of the data?

Comment: What is wrong with `result.groupby(['lat','lon'])`? pandas lets you group on multiple columns.

Comment: Oh, I guess you are correct. I was fooling myself into thinking it was more complicated than it actually was

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't the part

> At this point I would like to be able to do something like `result.groupby(('lat','lon'))`

exactly the answer you are looking for? It will groupby on unique values in as many columns as you want.

Example data:

```
key  time     data  lat  lon
3     1   0.231000   84    4
4     1   0.832310   22   11
5     1   1.210000   84    4
6     1   3.778231   22   11
8     1  15.450000   84    4
```

How to group on unique values in those two columns:

```
import pandas as pd

for name, group in df.groupby(["lat", "lon"]):
    print("Group indices: {}".format(name))
    print(group)
```

Output:

```
Group indices: (22, 11)
   key  time      data  lat  lon
1    4     1  0.832310   22   11
3    6     1  3.778231   22   11
Group indices: (84, 4)
   key  time    data  lat  lon
0    3     1   0.231   84    4
2    5     1   1.210   84    4
4    8     1  15.450   84    4
```

Isn't this exactly what you wanted or have I misunderstood something?